# Angular 7 Start date > end Date validation

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to angular working on a project. I am having a problem in the code.
Start date and end date:
start date >= enddate

It is working fine with my current logic in case of creating new record, but when I try to update any record and update end date, then the button remains disabled.
Anyone can help me with the code?

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="33" class="pr-4">
               <mat-label>Start Date</mat-label>
               <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker" name="startDate" formControlName="startDate"
                 required>
               <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
               <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
               <mat-error>Start Date is required!</mat-error>
             </mat-form-field>

             <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="33" class="pr-4">
               <mat-label>End Date</mat-label>
               <input matInput [matDatepicker]="endDatePicker"  

                  (dateChange) ="addEvent(academicYearForm.get('startDate').value,$event)"  name="endDate"  formControlName="endDate" required>
               <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
               <mat-datepicker #endDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
               <mat-error>End Date is required!</mat-error>
             </mat-form-field>
```

```js
addEvent(startDate,event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    if(event.value >= startDate){
        this.isDisabled = false;
    }else {
        this.isDisabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a debugger check the value of startdate and event.value in addEvent function. Posting a small example in stackblitz will help others to better assist you. Happy Coding...

Comment: where are you using `isDisabled ` ?

Comment: <button mat-raised-button  [disabled]="academicYearForm.invalid || academicYearForm.pristine || isDisabled"  (click) = "saveAcademicYear()">
        {{ pageType == 'edit' ? 'Update' : 'Save' }}
      </button>
Here i am using this isDisabled

Comment: what is the initial value of isDisabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced the same problem. you can solve this by 2 ways.

1- Use one of these libraries 
[ https://www.dunebook.com/best-javascript-calendar-libraries/ ]

2- Convert your date into milliseconds and then compare.

Comment: thanks, i have tried the second option. and it worked.